# how to verify if the group is sucessfully added for a folder in python

Tags: python, pywin32, dacl, win32con

I am using below to add a group name  in security tab for a folder through and its getting added. However in python how I can verify if  the group is added successfully.

```
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION,win32con.GENERIC_WRITE, groupw)
```

Comment: What do you mean "*how I can verify*"? Look at the *dir*'s Security tab. Also *PyWin32* functions throw exceptions on failures (so you can check that by testing with an invalid group).